# How to convert dictionary type [Int:[Int[Int:String]]] to [String:[String:[String:String]]]

Tags: dictionary, swift3, type-conversion

I currently have a dictionary in Swift which is a type of  `[Int:[Int[Int:String]]]`

I have tried to use

```
let myDict:[Int:[Int[Int:String]]] = //Values
let dictToStringDict = myDict as! [String:[String:[String:String]]]
```

The only problem is Xcode gives me the error `[Int:[Int[Int:String]]] is not convertible to [String:[String:[String:String]]]`

How would I convert `[Int:[Int[Int:String]]]` to `[String:[String:[String:String]]]`?

Comment: With a couple of repeat loops.

Comment: @vadian I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: What is unclear with *...is not convertible...*? ;-)

Comment: @vadian There could have been a built in function which would allow it.

Comment: Then the compiler would suggest to use it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Doing something like

```
    let myDict:[Int:[Int:[Int : String]]] = [Int:[Int:[Int : String]]]()
    let dictToStringDict = myDict as AnyObject
    let toanotjer = dictToStringDict as! [String:[String:[String:String]]]
```

Comment: *type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'*

Comment: i have updated the answer after testing on mine Xcode 8.1

Comment: it is not giving me any Error